# Why is my counter in my carousel returning negative values after reaching the 0 index and max index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, counter

Why is my counter going to a negative value after reaching the 0 index and max index? I have code that is supposed to be resetting the index value to the first or last index when this happens. When the user clicks on Next/Previous and they come to the beginning or end of the carousel the index of the slide should reset to the first or last index depending on the current index position.

My slides disappear when the user clicks next 6 times and then clicks on previous 3 times.

If anyone could assist me with this I would be very grateful!

```js
$(function() {
    // Default controls
    var defControls = {
        content: "img", // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
        showControls: true, // true/false shows/hides the carousel's navigational controls
        effect: "default", // supports default, fade, slide, verticalSlide, slidingFade
        effectDuration: 0.25, // to be used in conjunction with effect - adjust the time of the effect measured in seconds
        prevText: "&laquo; Previous", // previous button text
        nextText: "Next &raquo;", // next button text
        containerWidth: 600, // determines the width of the content container
        cycleback: false, // allows for cycling back through images
        autoplay: false, // automatically cycle through the slides in the carousel
        pauseTime: 10 // to be used in conjunction with autoplay - sets the pause time inbetween each slide
    };

    // Variable declarations
    var controls = {};

    // Checks for userControls
    if (typeof userControls !== "undefined") {
        controls = $.extend({}, defControls, userControls);
    } else {
        controls = defControls;
    }

    var contentType = $(controls.content);
    var $el = $("#showcase");
    var $leftArrow = "#left_arrow";
    var $rightArrow = "#right_arrow";
    var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
    var slideCount = $el.children().length;
    var slideContent = $el.children();
    var slideNum = 1;
    var counter = $(".active").index();

    // Checks if the content in the carousel is an img and then determines the width of the container based on the size of the content
    if (controls.content === "img") {
        controls.containerWidth = $(".slide").width();
    }

    // Preloads carousel with correct settings
    $el.css("width", controls.containerWidth);
    $el.find(contentType)[0].setAttribute("class", "active");

    // Checks to see if the setting for carousel controls are set to show on the page
    if (controls.showControls === true) {
        $(
            '<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' +
                $leftArrow.replace("#", "") +
                '">' +
                controls.prevText +
                '</a> <a href="#" id="' +
                $rightArrow.replace("#", "") +
                '">' +
                controls.nextText +
                "</a></div>"
        ).insertAfter("#showcase");
        $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").addClass("disabled");
    }

    // Checks to see if the setting for cycleback is enabled
    if (controls.cycleback === true) {
        $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").removeClass("disabled");
    }

    // Checks to see if the setting for autoplay is enabled
    if (controls.autoplay === true) {
        $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").removeClass("disabled");
        controls.cycleback = true;
        var interval;
        var timer = function() {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                $("#right_arrow").click();
            }, controls.pauseTime * 1000);
        };
        timer();
    }

    // Logic for the carousel effects
    function effects(action) {
        switch (controls.effect) {
            // Fade effect
            case "fade":
                if (controls.content == "img") {
                    $el.css("background", "#000");
                }

                $(".slide").stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 300, function() {
                    $(".active").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                });
                break;

            // Slide effect
            case "slide":
                if (action == "prev") {
                    $(".slide").css("left", -controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide")
                        .stop()
                        .animate({ left: -controls.containerWidth }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ left: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                            }
                        );
                } else if (action == "next") {
                    $(".slide").css("left", controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide")
                        .stop()
                        .animate({ left: controls.containerWidth }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ left: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                            }
                        );
                }
                break;

            case "verticalSlide":
                if (action == "prev") {
                    $(".slide").css("top", -controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide")
                        .stop()
                        .animate({ top: -controls.containerWidth }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ top: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                            }
                        );
                } else if (action == "next") {
                    $(".slide").css("top", controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide").stop().animate({ top: controls.containerWidth }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ top: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                            }
                        );
                }
                break;

            // Sliding fade effect
            case "slidingFade":
                if (action == "prev") {
                    $(".slide").css("left", -controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide").stop().animate({ left: -controls.containerWidth, opacity: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1400,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ left: 0, opacity: 1 }, controls.effectDuration * 1200);
                            }
                        );
                } else if (action == "next") {
                    $(".slide").css("left", controls.containerWidth);
                    $(".slide").stop().animate({ left: controls.containerWidth, opacity: 0 }, controls.effectDuration * 1400,
                            function() {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({ left: 0, opacity: 1 }, controls.effectDuration * 1200);
                            });
                }
                break;

            // Default effect
            case "default":
                break;
        }
    }

    // Checks for the first and last index in the carousel
    function checkSlide() {
        if (controls.cycleback === false) {
            if (slideNum == 1) {
                $($leftArrow).addClass("disabled");
            } else {
                $($leftArrow).removeClass("disabled");
            }

            if (slideNum == slideCount) {
                $($rightArrow).addClass("disabled");
            } else {
                $($rightArrow).removeClass("disabled");
            }
        } else {
            $($leftArrow).removeClass("disabled");
            $($rightArrow).removeClass("disabled");
        }
    }

    // Navigational logic for the previous/next buttons
    $(document).on("click", $leftArrow, function(e) {
        if (controls.cycleback === false) {
            if (slideNum > 1) {
                counter--;
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");
console.log(counter);
                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("prev");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum--;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            if (slideNum > 1) {
                counter--;
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");

                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("prev");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum--;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();

                // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    timer();
                }
            } else {
                counter = $(".active").index() + (slideNum - 1);
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");

                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("next");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum++;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();

                // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    timer();
                }
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", $rightArrow, function(e) {
        if (controls.cycleback === false) {
            if (slideNum < slideCount) {
                counter++;
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");
console.log(counter);
                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("next");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum++;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            if (slideNum < slideCount) {
                counter++;
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");

                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("next");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum++;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();

                // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    timer();
                }
            } else {
                counter = $(".active").index() - (slideCount - 1);
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");

                // Sends the effect value to the switch
                effects("next");
console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                slideNum++;

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();

                // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    timer();
                }
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#showcase {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: green;
}

.disabled {
 color: red !important;
}

.slide {
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.active {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase">
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=806" />
 <!-- <div class="slide">content 1</div>
 <div class="slide">content 2</div>
 <div class="slide">content 3</div> -->
</div>

<script>
userControls = {
 effectDuration : .5,
 cycleback : true
}
</script>
```

Comment: I find it interesting that autoplay is implemented via a call to `$("#right_arrow").click();`.  Consider *refactoring* your code so that you have two methods for traversing the slideshow: `prevSlide()` and `nextSlide()`.  Overall, your code suffers because it mixes side-effects (DOM manipulation with jQuery) with the traversal algorithm (moving forward and back in a set of slides).  Some cleanup in this regard will do you wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your counter is that it can't work for multiple clicks in any given direction.

The `eq(n)` is the problem why you get a blank picture. The larger indexes `(index > slideCount or index <  -1 * slideCount)` are causing it to go out of bounds.  The only reason why `eq(n)` worked on negative numbers because it was using the length of the array of slides as an of offset.

I fixed so that slideNum will reset when you reach 0 or slideCount and loop back.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Default controls
        var defControls = {
            content: "img", // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
            showControls: true, // true/false shows/hides the carousel's navigational controls
            effect: "default", // supports default, fade, slide, verticalSlide, slidingFade
            effectDuration: 0.25, // to be used in conjunction with effect - adjust the time of the effect measured in seconds
            prevText: "&laquo; Previous", // previous button text
            nextText: "Next &raquo;", // next button text
            containerWidth: 600, // determines the width of the content container
            cycleback: false, // allows for cycling back through images
            autoplay: false, // automatically cycle through the slides in the carousel
            pauseTime: 10 // to be used in conjunction with autoplay - sets the pause time inbetween each slide
        };

        // Variable declarations
        var controls = {};

        // Checks for userControls
        if (typeof userControls !== "undefined") {
            controls = $.extend({}, defControls, userControls);
        } else {
            controls = defControls;
        }

        var contentType = $(controls.content);
        var $el = $("#showcase");
        var $leftArrow = "#left_arrow";
        var $rightArrow = "#right_arrow";
        var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
        var slideCount = $el.children().length;
        var slideContent = $el.children();
        var slideNum = 1;
        var counter = $(".active").index();

        // Checks if the content in the carousel is an img and then determines the width of the container based on the size of the content
        if (controls.content === "img") {
            controls.containerWidth = $(".slide").width();
        }

        // Preloads carousel with correct settings
        $el.css("width", controls.containerWidth);
        $el.find(contentType)[0].setAttribute("class", "active");

        // Checks to see if the setting for carousel controls are set to show on the page
        if (controls.showControls === true) {
            $(
                '<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' +
                $leftArrow.replace("#", "") +
                '">' +
                controls.prevText +
                '</a> <a href="#" id="' +
                $rightArrow.replace("#", "") +
                '">' +
                controls.nextText +
                "</a></div>"
            ).insertAfter("#showcase");
            $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").addClass("disabled");
        }

        // Checks to see if the setting for cycleback is enabled
        if (controls.cycleback === true) {
            $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").removeClass("disabled");
        }

        // Checks to see if the setting for autoplay is enabled
        if (controls.autoplay === true) {
            $("#controls").find("#left_arrow").removeClass("disabled");
            controls.cycleback = true;
            var interval;
            var timer = function () {
                interval = setInterval(function () {
                    $("#right_arrow").click();
                }, controls.pauseTime * 1000);
            };
            timer();
        }

        // Logic for the carousel effects
        function effects(action) {
            switch (controls.effect) {
                // Fade effect
                case "fade":
                    if (controls.content == "img") {
                        $el.css("background", "#000");
                    }

                    $(".slide").stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, controls.effectDuration * 300, function () {
                        $(".active").stop().animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                    });
                    break;

                    // Slide effect
                case "slide":
                    if (action == "prev") {
                        $(".slide").css("left", -controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide")
                            .stop()
                            .animate({
                                    left: -controls.containerWidth
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                                function () {
                                    $(".active").stop().animate({
                                        left: 0
                                    }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                                }
                            );
                    } else if (action == "next") {
                        $(".slide").css("left", controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide")
                            .stop()
                            .animate({
                                    left: controls.containerWidth
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                                function () {
                                    $(".active").stop().animate({
                                        left: 0
                                    }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                                }
                            );
                    }
                    break;

                case "verticalSlide":
                    if (action == "prev") {
                        $(".slide").css("top", -controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide")
                            .stop()
                            .animate({
                                    top: -controls.containerWidth
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                                function () {
                                    $(".active").stop().animate({
                                        top: 0
                                    }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                                }
                            );
                    } else if (action == "next") {
                        $(".slide").css("top", controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide").stop().animate({
                                top: controls.containerWidth
                            }, controls.effectDuration * 800,
                            function () {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({
                                    top: 0
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 1000);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    break;

                    // Sliding fade effect
                case "slidingFade":
                    if (action == "prev") {
                        $(".slide").css("left", -controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide").stop().animate({
                                left: -controls.containerWidth,
                                opacity: 0
                            }, controls.effectDuration * 1400,
                            function () {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({
                                    left: 0,
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 1200);
                            }
                        );
                    } else if (action == "next") {
                        $(".slide").css("left", controls.containerWidth);
                        $(".slide").stop().animate({
                                left: controls.containerWidth,
                                opacity: 0
                            }, controls.effectDuration * 1400,
                            function () {
                                $(".active").stop().animate({
                                    left: 0,
                                    opacity: 1
                                }, controls.effectDuration * 1200);
                            });
                    }
                    break;

                    // Default effect
                case "default":
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Checks for the first and last index in the carousel
        function checkSlide() {
            if (controls.cycleback === false) {
                if (slideNum == 1) {
                    $($leftArrow).addClass("disabled");
                } else {
                    $($leftArrow).removeClass("disabled");
                }

                if (slideNum == slideCount) {
                    $($rightArrow).addClass("disabled");
                } else {
                    $($rightArrow).removeClass("disabled");
                }
            } else {
                $($leftArrow).removeClass("disabled");
                $($rightArrow).removeClass("disabled");
            }
        }

        // Navigational logic for the previous/next buttons
        $(document).on("click", $leftArrow, function (e) {
            if (controls.cycleback === false) {
                if (slideNum > 1) {
                    $(".active").addClass("slide");
                    $(".active").removeClass("active");

                    slideNum--;
                    if (slideNum == -1) {
                        slideNum = slideCount;
                    }
                    counter = slideNum - 1;
                    console.log(counter);
                    // Sends the effect value to the switch
                    effects("prev");
                    console.log(counter);
                    $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");

                    // Checks the current slide index
                    checkSlide();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {

                slideNum--;
                if (slideNum == -1) {
                    slideNum = slideCount - 1;
                }
                counter = slideNum - 1;
                if (counter < 0) {
                    counter = counter + slideCount;
                }

                effects("prev");
                $(".active").addClass("slide");
                $(".active").removeClass("active");
                console.log(counter);
                $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");

                // Checks the current slide index
                checkSlide();

                // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    timer();
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", $rightArrow, function (e) {
            if (controls.cycleback === false) {
                if (slideNum < slideCount) {
                    counter = slideNum;
                    $(".active").addClass("slide");
                    $(".active").removeClass("active");
                    console.log(counter);
                    // Sends the effect value to the switch
                    effects("next");
                    console.log(counter);
                    $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");

                    if (slideNum < slideCount) {
                        slideNum++;
                    }

                    // Checks the current slide index
                    checkSlide();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                if (slideNum < slideCount) {
                    counter = slideNum;
                    $(".active").addClass("slide");
                    $(".active").removeClass("active");

                    // Sends the effect value to the switch
                    effects("next");
                    console.log(counter);
                    $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                    slideNum++;

                    if (slideNum == slideCount) {
                        slideNum = 0;
                    } else if (slideNum < 0) {
                        slideNum = slideCount + slideNum;
                    }

                    // Checks the current slide index
                    checkSlide();

                    // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                    if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        timer();
                    }
                } else {
                    counter = (slideCount - slideNum);
                    $(".active").addClass("slide");
                    $(".active").removeClass("active");

                    // Sends the effect value to the switch
                    effects("next");
                    console.log(counter);
                    $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass("active");
                    slideNum++;

                    if (slideNum == slideCount) {
                        slideNum = 0;
                    } else if (slideNum < 0) {
                        slideNum = slideCount + slideNum;
                    }

                    // Checks the current slide index
                    checkSlide();

                    // Resets the autoplay timer if previous is clicked
                    if (controls.autoplay === true) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        timer();
                    }
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The index successfully resets upon hitting and going beyond the max index. However, when you click on the previous button from the start, the index goes to -1 instead of the max index.

Comment: @Peter Fixed it. No more negative indexes.

Comment: The problem with fiddle example is that you have the same slide twice. One in the begin and one at the end. For the negative, I used the slideCount to offset the index to be a positive number.

Comment: Nitrodmr, I saw that almost immediately after I posted. Sorry about that. Thank you for your help I will accept this as the answer but what did you do to address the negative index?

Comment: `if (counter < 0) {
counter = counter + slideCount;
}`